# Customise a combination of Quiet and Block

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, attributes

I would like to define a function that shuts up all warnings.

My first go was:

```
Silence[x_] := Block[{}, Quiet[x]];
```

I have also tried working with pure functions:

```
Silence = Block[{},Quiet[#]]&;
```

But neither of them seem to work when applied as a function (`Silence`), whereas they work when I write them down explicitly. Why?

Comment: Specifically speaking, just use `Attributes@Silence = HoldAll;
Silence[x_] := Block[{}, Quiet[x]];` or `Silence = Function[x, Block[{}, Quiet[x]], HoldAll];` :)

Comment: @xzczd Thanks a lot!